Spring Batch adding CRLF at the end of each file when writing it to FlatFile
I'm using Spring Batch, its writing CRLF at the end of each line when using org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter. Having CRLF at the end of each file creating issues for other system. How can we avoid this?
<bean id="cvsWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="somepath"/>
    <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true"/>
    <property name="encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="lineAggregator" ref="someLineAggregator"/>
    <property name="headerCallback" ref="someHeaderCallback" />
</bean>
<bean id="someMultiResource" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="name" value="multiResourceWriter" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="cvsWriter" />
    <property name="resource" value="somepath" />
    <property name="itemCountLimitPerResource" value="2000000" />
    <property name="resourceSuffixCreator" ref="suffixCreator" />
</bean>


Specify the line ending you want to have that is what the lineSeparator property is for on the FlatFileItemWriter. By default it will use the one from the system you are running on. That or fix your other system to don't be bother with the line ending but accept all.

As @M.Deinum said, lineSeparator is what you are looking for.

@M.Deinum There should be a reason, but why don't you post your comments as answers? It is not the first time that I see you answering questions correctly by posting comments, instead of an answer. Anyway, thank you for all your help to Spring Batch community!!

The FlatFileItemReader exposes a lineSeparator property.

Public setter for the line separator. Defaults to the System property line.separator.

The javadoc states the above. It will set this property to the default used by your platform. Which in your case is using CRLF. You can force it to use something else by adding this to your configuration.
<bean id="cvsWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="somepath"/>
    <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true"/>
    <property name="encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="lineAggregator" ref="someLineAggregator"/>
    <property name="headerCallback" ref="someHeaderCallback" />
    <property name="lineSeparator" value="&#13;" />
</bean>

The above will set \r as the line ending, using &#10; will use \n as the line ending. Use which you need.
